# Using 'TestCoroutineExceptionHandler' is an error. Deprecated for removal without a replacement

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines

Error Log : Using 'TestCoroutineExceptionHandler' is an error. Deprecated for removal without a replacement. It may be to define one's own `CoroutineExceptionHandler` if you just need to handle 'uncaught exceptions without a special `TestCoroutineScope` integration.

I have a project to create Unit Tests on StoriesViewModel, when I run it, there is an error, can you help to make my project work.

StoriesViewModelTest.kt

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class StoriesViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @get:Rule
    val mainDispatcherRules = MainDispatcherRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var storyRepository: StoryRepository
    private var dummyStory = DataDummy.generateDummyStory()

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun `when Get Story Should Not Null and Return Success`() = mainDispatcherRules.runBlockingTest {
        val data: PagingData<Story> = StoryPagingSource.snapshot(dummyStory.listStory)
        val expectedResponse = MutableLiveData<PagingData<Story>>()

        expectedResponse.value = data
        Mockito.`when`(storyRepository.getListStories()).thenReturn(expectedResponse)

        val storiesViewModel = StoriesViewModel(storyRepository)
        val actualStory: PagingData<Story> = storiesViewModel.getListStory.getOrAwaitValue()

        val differ = AsyncPagingDataDiffer(
            diffCallback = ListStoriesAdapter.DIFF_CALLBACK,
            updateCallback = noopListUpdateCallback,
            workerDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main,
        )
        differ.submitData(actualStory)

        assertNotNull(differ.snapshot())
        assertEquals(dummyStory.listStory, differ.snapshot())
        assertEquals(dummyStory.listStory.size, differ.snapshot().size)
        assertEquals(dummyStory.listStory[0].name, differ.snapshot()[0]?.name)
    }
}

class StoryPagingSource : PagingSource<Int, LiveData<List<Story>>>() {
    companion object {
        fun snapshot(items: List<Story>): PagingData<Story> {
            return PagingData.from(items)
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, LiveData<List<Story>>>): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, LiveData<List<Story>>> {
        return LoadResult.Page(emptyList(), 0, 1)
    }
}

val noopListUpdateCallback = object : ListUpdateCallback {
    override fun onInserted(position: Int, count: Int) {}
    override fun onRemoved(position: Int, count: Int) {}
    override fun onMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {}
    override fun onChanged(position: Int, count: Int, payload: Any?) {}
}
```

DataDummy.kt :

```
object DataDummy {
    fun generateErrorDummyStory(): StoryResponse {
        return StoryResponse(
            error = true,
            message = "error",
            listStory = arrayListOf(
                Story(
                    id = "id",
                    name = "name",
                    description = "description",
                    photoUrl = "photoUrl",
                    createdAt = "createdAt",
                    lat = 0.01,
                    lon = 0.01
                )
            )
        )
    }
}
```

MainDispatcherRule.kt :

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainDispatcherRule(private val dispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()):
    TestWatcher(),
    TestCoroutineScope by createTestCoroutineScope(TestCoroutineDispatcher() + TestCoroutineExceptionHandler() + dispatcher) {
    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        cleanupTestCoroutines()
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

Error Log :
[image]